# Unable to understand what kind of design pattern this is?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am not able to understand the below design. Let's assume the below classes and interfaces

```
interface A
{
   ....
}
class B implements A
{
   ....
}
class C extends B implements A
{
   ...
}
```

I found this design in one of the IBM frameworks (wcs order framework). So here why class C needs to implement A ?

What are the different scenarios in which you can use this design?

What type of design pattern is this?

Comment: Of course, `C` already inherits `A`, so technically there is no reason to declare `implements A` again. But it might be more obvious to those who want to use instances of `C`. So it is probably done to enhance readability.

Comment: Simple Java Object Orient way. This is not a pattern, it is a language skill.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can not inherit from more than one parent, but you can implement more interface.

C don't have to implement interface A because B already did, but you can override implemented methods.

Comment: I think the OP is aware of this, but is asking why repeat **implements A** on C since it should be implicit by extending B

Comment: True. It makes no sense. ;)

Comment: well, actually it makes some, as @isnot2bad noticed in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here, class C doesn't need to implement interface A. (as isnot2bad's comment stated)
The only reason is to make the fact explicit, without having to lookup the parent class(es) declarations. It could be a historical IBM-WCS-team convention.

This practice goes against the DRY principle and modern IDEs can already help.
For example, RAD/Eclipse can show all implemented interfaces with Ctrl+T x2 (supertype hierarchy).